# Payment automation of Paytm using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the payment process (Paytm) using selenium , When I give sendkeys of username and password. It dosent type in the given box. Can I Get some help

Answer (score 0):

It is because its under iframe.
Try to switch to the iframe and then perform sendkeys.

```
objDriver.switchTo().frame(
     objDriver.findElement(By
        .xpath("//iframe[@ng-hide='showVerificationScreen']")));
objDriver.findElement(By.id("mobileNumber")).sendKeys("xyz");
```